# Swift изменить Title в AlertController

Tags: xcode, swift

Есть alert, изменить цвет кнопок понятно как, через tint, но вот изменить сам заголовок алерта с черного на другой, никак не выходит.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let actionAlert = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .default) { (action) in
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let actionAlert = UIAlertAction(title: "ОК", style: .default) { (action) in

                tableView.reloadData()
            }
            alert.addAction(actionAlert)
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            alert.view.tintColor = UIColor.lightGray

            if let visualEffectView = alert.view.searchVisualEffectsSubview()
            {
                visualEffectView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: .dark)
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте attributeString

```
let yourString = "Title"

    let range = (yourString as NSString).range(of: yourString)

    let attribute = NSMutableAttributedString.init(string: yourString)
    attribute.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red , range: range)
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "",  preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.setValue(attribute, forKey: "attributedTitle")
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default) { (action: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
    }

    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Работает, как нужно) спасибо